# Regular expression to check format string string:string any occurrence

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build regex to match - Test get:all words:test

can start with a word then space and followed by any occurrence of word:word separated by space.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z]+/s(^[a-zA-Z]+:^[a-zA-Z]+/s)*"
```

Comment: You can use: `^\w+(?:\s+\w+:\w+)*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added extra start of string anchors, `^`, inside the pattern, and you need to remove them for sure.

Besides, the whitespace patterns must be written as `\s` and the first `\s` must be moved inside the repeated group that should be converted into a non-capturing one (`(?:...)`) for better performance.

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4lkS1/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters, `:`, one or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string (or use `\z` to match the very end of string).

If you meant to allow any word chars (letters, digits, connector punctuation) then replace each `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w`.

If you need to support just any Unicode letters, replace each `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}`.

Comment: @user1768187 You are welcome. I added more information to let you tweak the pattern as you see fit, Unicode matching is not a trivial task in many situations.